# Local vs Nonlocal electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, non-locality

I am having a hard time to understand the difference between local and nonlocal electrodynamics.

Does the former refer to the case when the charge (i.e electron) can be localized and the latter refer to the case when the position of the electron cannot be localized due to Heisenberg uncertainty principle?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In what context have you seen these terms?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, in one particular context, this distinction means:

Does the particle/material response depend on only the fields at the same location? (Local)

Or does the particle/material response depend on the fields at the same location *as well as* fields at other, nearby locations. (Nonlocal)